# creating dynamic hash with key and value in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create Hash with dynamic key and respective values. For example like this

```
hash = {1 => 23.67, 1 => 78.44, 3 => 66.33, 12 => 44.2}
```

Something like this in which 1,2,12 are array index. I hope it is understandable. I am trying with the syntax from ROR tutorials.

Like this

```
 test = Hash.new 

  for i in 0..23
   if (s.duration.start.hour == array[i].hour)
     s.sgs.each do |s1|
       case s1.type.to_s
       when 'M'
         test ={i => s1.power} # here I am trying to create hash like give example in which i is for loop value
       when 'L'
         puts "to be done done"
       else
         puts "Not Found"
       end
     end
   end
 end
end
```

Updated code

```
 test = Hash.new
 for i in 0..23
   if (s.duration.start.hour == array[i].hour)
     s.sgs.each do |s1|
       case s.type.to_s
       when 'M'
         puts s1.power;
         test[i] =  s1._power
       when 'L'
         puts "to be done"
       else
         puts "Not  Found"
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

Results

on traversing

```
for t in 0..array.size
  puts test[t]
end
```

Results :

```
t = 68.6 # which is last value
```

and expected

```
t = 33.4
t = 45.6 etc
```

Sample logs

```
after assign {23=>#<BigDecimal:7f3a1e9a6870,'0.3E2',9(18)>}
before assign {23=>#<BigDecimal:7f3a1e9a6870,'0.2E2',9(18)>}
after assign {23=>#<BigDecimal:7f3a1e9ce550,'-0.57E2',9(18)>}
before assign {23=>#<BigDecimal:7f3a1e9ce550,'-0.57E2',9(18)>}
```

if any other optimised solution is there would be good thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are re-assigning `test` with a new hash on each iteration. You should add to it, so instead of

```
test ={i => s1.power}
```

you should do:

```
test[i] = s1.power
```

This *sets* the value of key `i` to `s1.power`

---

If you want to keep an *array* of all the values for a given key, I would suggest the following (more ruby-ish) solution:

```
hour_idx = array.find_index { |item| s.duration.start.hour == item.hour }

values = case s.type.to_s
  when 'M'
    s.sgs.map(&:_power)
  when 'L'
    puts "to be done"
  else
    puts "Not  Found"
  end

test = { hour_idx => values }
```

What I'm doing here is:

1. Find the `hour_idx` which is relevant to the current `s` (I assume there is only one such item)
2. Create an array of all the relevant values according to `s.type` (if it is `'M'` an array of all the `_power` of `s.sgs`, for `'L'` whatever map you need, and `nil` otherwise)
3. Create the target hash using the values set in #1 and #2...

Comment: but When I am checking length for it, it shows only 1 but it goes in this switch case more then that...i Think it is something related to initialization of Hash with Hash.new

Comment: Have you made the change I've suggested? your original code does not add keys, it simply creates a new hash of size 1 each time, and overrides the previous hash...

Comment: yes, I did as you mention, i checked it just now, it overriding values and keeping last one only....

Comment: Also expected result vs actual result

Comment: Add some logs to your iteration: `puts "before assign #{test}"` before the `test[i] = ...` line, and `puts "after assign #{test}"` after that line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54870/discussion-between-uri-agassi-and-user1618).